# Populating posts with replies (sample_data.rake)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I have three models: `Post`, `Replies` and `User`. `Reply` s a nested resource of `Post`:

**replies.rb:**

```
class Reply < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post, :counter_cache => true
  .
  .
  .
```

**post. rb:**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActionView::Helpers

  attr_accessible :title, :content

  belongs_to :user

  has_many :replies, dependent: :destroy
  .
  .
  .
```

This is what I have in my `sample_data.rake` file:

sample_data.rake:

```
def make_users
  admin = User.create!(name:     "Example User",
                       email:    "example@railstutorial.org",
                       password: "foobar",
                       password_confirmation: "foobar")
  admin.toggle!(:admin)
  99.times do |n|
    name  = Faker::Name.name
    email = "example-#{n+1}@railstutorial.org"
    password  = "password"
    User.create!(name:     name,
                 email:    email,
                 password: password,
                 password_confirmation: password)
  end
end

def make_posts
  users = User.all(limit: 6)
  50.times do
    title = Faker::Lorem.sentence(1)
    content = Faker::Lorem.sentence(5)
    users.each { |user| user.posts.create!(title: title,
                                           content: content) }
  end
end
```

This is how I create replies:

```
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @reply = @post.replies.build(params[:reply])
    @reply.user_id = current_user.id
    if @reply.save
     # do this
    else
     # do this
    end
  end
```

How to populate a certain number of posts with replies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just call a method `make_reply` within the `50.times` loop of `make_posts`.  Perhaps you can have some conditions that determine how many replies, or whatever, but it's essentially the same.  The key is that the parent (Post) needs to have been saved in order for it to have an id.  But this is almost exactly what your create controller method does already, right?

So something like

```
def make_posts
  users = User.all(limit: 6)
  50.times do
    title = Faker::Lorem.sentence(1)
    content = Faker::Lorem.sentence(5)
    users.each do |user| 
      user.posts.create!(title: title, content: content)
      # 1 post is now saved, get it, then make reply
      post = user.posts.first  # maybe you already have this as a return from create?
      make_reply(post)
    end
  end
end

def make_reply(post)
  # find a random user to be the replier
  replier = User.find method_that_returns_random_user
  content = Faker::Lorem.sentence(10)  # or whatever
  post.replies.create!(user: replier.id, content: content)
end
```

You'll need a way to come up with a valid userid to be the replier.

Comment: That's the part I don't know how to do: `User.find method_that_returns_random_user`

Answer (score 1):

The rand method returns a random integer up to the value passed in, so you could do something like:

```
def make_reply(post)
  # So we dont query the database for the size of the users table each time
  @user_count ||= User.count
  replier = User.find(rand(@user_count))
  content = Faker::Lorem.sentence(10)  # or whatever
  post.replies.create!(user: replier.id, content: content)
end
```